# placing an image and text hyper lin over each other

Tags: html

I have the code below to display the image and the code as a hyperlink. But I would like the image placed behind the text and person can click on either

```
<a href="#"> <h1>test</h1> <img scr="#"/></a>
```

Comment: `<h1>` is a block tag. it must not be used inside an inline tag ie`<a>`

Comment: <a src=""> ? .Dont invent your own html.Use <a href="">

Comment: why dont you use background-image on the a tag ?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to achieve this:

```
<a href=".." style="background-image:url('image.png');"> test </a>
```

Here you can see more info about `background-image`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image
You have syntax error in your code, you must use `<h1>` outside the `<a>` tags, like this:

```
<h1><a href=".." style="background-image:url('image.png');"> test </a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `position: absolute` so the text will be on the top of the image.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <img src="http://spi3uk.itvnet.lv/upload2/articles/54/542197/images/Jauka-vasara-8.jpg"/>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    position: relative;
}

a h1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykUzr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use background:

```
<a href="..." style="background-image: url('...');"><h1>test</h1></a>
```

But if you want, you can use another variant (negative margin):

```
<a href="..."><h1 style="height: 24px;">test</h1><img style="margin-top: -24px;" src="..."/></a>
```

Or absolute position:

```
<a href="..."><h1 style="position: absolute; z-index: 9;">test</h1><img src="..."/></a>
```

P.S. You have some typos in code: `scr` -> `src` and `<\h1>` -> `</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends how you'd be using this.

Either set is as a background image instead of adding an img-tag.
But that would mean you'd have to set the height. Otherwise your image would crop.

...or you can set the (wouldn't use h1 in this case for semantic reasons) span with the text to:

**CSS**

```
span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and then position it wherever you want inside the image.